# How would you answer - What is Tor?

Tags: tor

if some one asked you what is Tor ? how would you answer it?

i understand Tor is a network of specially configured nodes, commonly called relays or bridges which transmits traffic. From a client to a destination, usually the internet through this is not always the case. But it is also a tool to aid privacy. i also understand the onion routing, of encrypting the packet several times so it can only be decrypted by the node resposble, and each node only knows where the packet came from and going to, making it very hard to trace the entire circuit

but this i find is not a good answer, and if a person came up to you in the street and asked What is Tor what would be your answer

My answer would be : Tor's the network to support what people refer to as the 'darknet'

just curious to hear what others what describe Tor to another person in a few lines

Answer (score 1):

"Tor is a network of virtual tunnels that allows people and groups to improve their privacy and security on the Internet. It also enables software developers to create new communication tools with built-in privacy features. Tor provides the foundation for a range of applications that allow organizations and individuals to share information over public networks without compromising their privacy.

Individuals use Tor to keep websites from tracking them and their family members, or to connect to news sites, instant messaging services, or the like when these are blocked by their local Internet providers. Tor's hidden services let users publish web sites and other services without needing to reveal the location of the site. Individuals also use Tor for socially sensitive communication: chat rooms and web forums for rape and abuse survivors, or people with illnesses." - https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en